# What is the likelihood in this situation?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Suppose X and Y are binary and we assume

$P(X=1|Y=0)=0$;

$P(X=0|Y=0)=1$;

$P(X=1|Y=1)=\theta$; and

$P(X=0|Y=1)=1-\theta$

Does the likelihood function look like this?

$$L(\theta|X,Y)=0^{\text{#instances where X=1 and Y=0}} \cdot 1^{\text{# instances where X=0 and Y=0}} \cdot \theta^{\text{#instances where X=1 and Y=1}} \cdot (1-\theta)^{\text{#instances where X=0 and Y=1}}
$$
If this is correct, how can I deal with the situation when I observe some instances {X=1 and Y=0}? Does the MLE of theta remain the same given that the likelihood function becomes 0?

Comment: A value of zero for a likelihood means your model conflicts with the evidence.  Adopt a different or more flexible model.

Comment: I see. But what if it doesn't? So there are no instances where X=1 and Y=0. is the likelihood function I've written correct?

Comment: It looks OK, if too complicated.  It simplifies greatly because you may throw out all data for which $Y=0$ and ignore $Y$ completely, thereby reducing your question to one about the likelihood for a Binomial sample--whose value you can look up and compare to your expression.